# Are lots of exceptions bad design in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am currently wrapping a C Library in Java, making it easier to use and work within OO-Programming. The C Library uses error codes (int return value) and Out-Parameter for data manipulation. I am not necessarily a fan of error codes, so I would like to create some custom Exception classes that I can throw if my library detects an error code other than "success".

The only problem is that the amount of Exceptions that might be raised by every single method is very high (There are some error codes that can be returned from every C library function, like "Device_Not_Connected"). It has been a while since I last programmed in Java, so, I really don't know what the situation is with Exceptions in Java.

1. Are methods that throw a lot of different exceptions bad design?
2. Do I have to handle the exceptions, or is there a way of simply ignoring it?
3. If I can ignore an exception, does it bubble up the call tree (like in Python for example)?
4. Are there any alternatives to exceptions in Java besides error codes and no-ops?

Comment: A good general rule of thumb is to have checked exceptions for a condition that the caller can recover from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are methods that throw a lot of different exceptions bad design?

If used right clearly no! An exception basically is just a possible return state which is out of the scope of the technical purpose of the method. E.g. if the method should read an value from a device null or any value should be returned using the return type. But throwing a custom DeviceNotConnectedException to state that something went wrong when you are not able to read a return value instead of simply returnung null is 100% best practice. And if 10 things can go wrong then it is okay to state 10 possible exceptions.

> Do i have to handle the exceptions, or is there a way of simply ignoring it?

When you don't catch an exception you will have to declare the method it occurs in with "public void myMethod() throws MyExcp {..}" and so on in every method calling this method, that method caller and so on. If you hand it to the main-method and it's not handled there it will crash the programm.

> If i can ignore an exception, does it bubble up the call tree (like in Python for example)?

See above.

> Are there any alternatives to exceptions in Java besides error codes and no-ops?

Not as far as I know but I'm not an expert.

Comment: If you extend RuntimeException they won't have to be explicitly declared in the method signature, and they automatically bubble upwards in the call chain. IMO, RuntimeExceptions are preferable to checked ones except for exceptions that can be recovered from in some meaningful way.

Comment: @marthursson That was exactly what i was searching for!

Comment: @marthursson your opinion -> ["Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Comment: @AndyTurner That i basically how i would handle exceptions in python. What i wanted is the implicit bubbling up the call chain. I hate cluttering my code with rethrow code.

Comment: @AndyTurner: It appears my opinion aligns with the one championed by the people that created the language. Splendid :)

Comment: @marthursson I wouldn't necessarily consider this the opinion of the (original) language creators: there are enough violations of this rule in the standard API to make me believe that this is a post-hoc rule-of-thumb. It would be interesting to know when this was decided (judging by [this](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/exceptions7.html), before 1998)

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely throw an exception if something goes wrong that is connected to IO (files, devices, user input). You do not need to define a different exception class for all the different error codes. If the handling of the error codes is quite similar, you can use the same exception, like

```
throw new IOException("Device not connected");
```

If possible, you should avoid throwing around too many exceptions that are connected to wrong parameters etc. Establish check functions for the user (like "containsKey") so that need not "try and catch" such things.

Comment: I am not really able to validate the parameters beforehand, as it depends on the state if the device the C library communicates with. It's not really the most intuitive API i have seen :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an inheritance hierarchy for your Exception classes, so that a method signature defines few [or even only one] general Exception class, regardless how many specific Exceptions you throw in the method's body.

```
public void myMethod() throws MyGeneralException {
  ...

  throw new MySpecific1Exception();
  .....

  throw new MySpecific2Exception();

}
```

The callers will have the freedom of choice to handle specific Exceptions or the general ones.

Option 1:

```
try {
    myMethod();
} catch (MyGeneralException e) {
   ....
}
```

Option 2:

```
try {
    myMethod();
} catch (MySpecific1Exception e) {
....
} catch (MySpecific2Exception e) {
....
}
```

Comment: I thought it only worked the other way around? Catching derived exceptions with a base exception catch clause?

Comment: I have added an example. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Sometimes i am impressed by Java, at least after programming C++ for a while!